# Plotting a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to return a plot similar to this, but as a stacked bar plot (females stacked on top of males):
[image: Example]

With Group 1 /2 being the years and Female/Male the sources (e.g Facebook, Google Ads etc).

This is the code I have written for my graph:

```
grouped = filtered.loc[filtered.groupby('anonymous_id')['utm_source']
                                         .apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index())]\
                            .dropna(subset=['utm_source'])
grouped_counts = grouped.groupby(['year','utm_source'])['Won'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

This code returns this graph:
[image: My Graph]

Here is a sample of my data:

```
      year  utm_source  Won                          anonymous_id
0     2018         NaN   No  0000f8ea-3aa6-4423-9247-1d9580d378e1
36    2018  google_ads   No  0008cb14-c833-494f-aa33-2caca8f91ca1
45    2018         NaN   No  000223b0-5278-418d-b9b1-b384024d31a9
46    2018         NaN   No  00037bad-bb90-4836-a9fa-61cbd44e480f
49    2019         NaN  Yes  0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
50    2019         NaN  Yes  0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
51    2019         NaN  Yes  0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
52    2019         NaN  Yes  0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
53    2019         NaN  Yes  0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
54    2019         NaN  Yes  0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78
```

Comment: That's not the focal point, I want my chart to be stacked, but I want to group all sources under their respective years,..like the first graph all 2017 entries are shown in one section, then 2018 etc @Brennan

Comment: Thanks. Deleted my first comment. [Here is what I think you would need to do](https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2018/01/add-second-x-axis-below-first-x-axis-python-matplotlib-pyplot.html). I'm not sure it can only be done with pandas. If you can share the rest of the code, I can write an answer and test.

Comment: maybe this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965009/grouped-x-axis-variability-plot-in-python) would be useful