# How to plot different bars for every value in a column, where every plot corresponds to a value in another column?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this dataframe as shown below:

```
data = [['AK','Coal',24457],
['AK','Natural ',222867],
['AK','Other ',15],
['AK','Petro',83848],
['AL','Coal ',169877],
['AL','Natural ',10692],
['AL','Other ',2631],
['AL','Petro',235853]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['STATE','ENERGY','CONSUME'])
```

I am trying to plot it on a graph, which needs to look like this image:
[image]

Every bar corresponds to 'CONSUME' value for the respective 'ENERGY'.
It is like grouping the values based on 'STATE' and plotting different bar based on 'ENERGY'.
So basically, every 'STATE' would have 4 bars indicating 4 different 'ENERGY' values.
I did try a few things, but they didn't work the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just modifying the code given by [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54965122/6660373) in one of his answer. Take a look at that answer also.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby
import numpy as np 
%matplotlib inline

data = [['AK','Coal',24457],
['AK','Natural ',222867],
['AK','Other ',15],
['AK','Petro',83848],
['AL','Coal ',169877],
['AL','Natural ',10692],
['AL','Other ',2631],
['AL','Petro',235853]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['STATE','ENERGY','CONSUME']) 
df = df.set_index(['STATE','ENERGY', 'STATE'])['CONSUME'].unstack()


def add_line(ax, xpos, ypos):
    line = plt.Line2D([xpos, xpos], [ypos + .1, ypos],
                      transform=ax.transAxes, color='gray')
    line.set_clip_on(False)
    ax.add_line(line)

def label_len(my_index,level):
    labels = my_index.get_level_values(level)
    return [(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in groupby(labels)]

def label_group_bar_table(ax, df):
    ypos = -.1
    scale = 1./df.index.size
    for level in range(df.index.nlevels)[::-1]:
        pos = 0
        for label, rpos in label_len(df.index,level):
            lxpos = (pos + .5 * rpos)*scale
            ax.text(lxpos, ypos, label, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes)
            add_line(ax, pos*scale, ypos)
            pos += rpos
        add_line(ax, pos*scale , ypos)
        ypos -= .1

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')
#Below 2 lines remove default labels
ax.set_xticklabels('')
ax.set_xlabel('')
label_group_bar_table(ax, df)
```

[image]

Comment: just print df you will get to know why.

Comment: Actually, I tried, but in the reset_index, we don't need to specify 'STATE' column twice. I went through the original post. They had 3 columns over which the plot had to be shown. I have only two columns. Your code worked! Thank you so much